# Par quel pronom de la troisième personne du singulier faut-il remplacer le groupe de mots "une personne" ou "la personne" dans une 2ème préposition

Tags: grammaire

J'ai souvent du mal à remplacer le groupe de mots **une personne** ou **la personne**  par un pronom personnel masculin ou féminin dans une deuxième phrase ou préposition après l'avoir cité dans une première. Exemples:

- j'ai vu **une personne rentrer** dans la chambre des garçons. **Il** était revêtu d'un manteau rouge.
- j'ai vu **la personne** tout de suite sans savoir **qu'elle** nous quitterait à tout jamais.

Comment: Va relire la dédicace du *Petit prince*, tu seras très vite persuadé que ça marche :)

Answer (score 2):

Le pronom féminin est attendu :

> J'ai vu une personne rentrer dans la chambre des garçons. **Elle** était vêtu**e** d'un manteau rouge.

Utiliser le masculin pourrait servir à informer qu'il s'agit d'un homme (par [syllepse grammaticale](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4097)), mais mieux vaut dire alors :

> J'ai vu un homme rentrer.... Il était vêtu d'un manteau rouge.

On rencontre la situation inverse avec *quelqu'un* quand il représente une femme, *quelqu'une* n'étant quasiment jamais utilisé, contrairement à *quelques-unes*.

Dans la phrase suivante, la syllepse n'est pas dans les usages ([encore que...](http://alafortunedumot.blogs.lavoixdunord.fr/tag/accord+en+genre+apr%C3%A8s+%22quelqu%27un+qui%22)), car on ne connait pas le sexe de la personne en question :

> J'ai vu quelqu'un rentrer dans la chambre des garçons. <s>Elle était **vêtue**</s> d'un manteau rouge.

Il faut écrire: *Il était vếtu...*

L'accord s'imposera en revanche si le sexe est précisé entretemps :

> J'ai vu quelqu'un rentrer dans la chambre des garçons. *C'était une femme*. Elle était **vêtue** d'un manteau rouge.

Comment: En effet, la seconde phrase est agrammaticale car en français "le masculin l'emporte"... ne sachant pas qui est désigné par "quelqu'un", à défaut il faut utiliser le masculin ensuite. Ce qui en effet est différent de "la personne" qui dans ce cas est un sujet féminin d'un point de vue purement grammatical.